# Cannot format string to datetime properly

Tags: python, datetime

I'm not familiar with datetime object. I'd like to convert a string to datetime.
Expected result `2020-03-01`

I tried
`datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-03-01', "%Y-%m-%d")`

It returns `datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0)`

Also tried `datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-03-01', "%Y-%m-%d").date()`

It returns `datetime.date(2020, 3, 1)`

How to get the result I want ?

Comment: You have done exactly what you said you wanted.  You have a `datetime` object that maps to 2020/03/01.  If you want a string, then you should have said so.  That's what `strftime` is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strftime()` is used for formatting `datetime` objects into strings.

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-03-01', "%Y-%m-%d").strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
#'2020-03-01'
```

Or you can simply

```
print(datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-03-01', "%Y-%m-%d").date())
#2020-03-01
```

Comment: I'd like the result to be datetime

Comment: Then you already have what you want? `datetime` objects are `datetime(year, month, day, etc..)` if you want it in a specific format you need to output it with `strftime()`

Comment: As I mentioned in the question already, my returned result is `datetime.date(2020, 3, 1)` from `datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-03-01', "%Y-%m-%d").date()`. I want '2020-03-01' and data type is datetime

Comment: @Osca You literally already have this. `datetime()` returns a date PLUS a time, always. Even if that time is `00:00:00`. `date()` returns only the date portions. If you want to display a `datetime()` in a specific format you use `strftime()`, else it is stored simply as a `datetime` object with no reference to format.

Comment: According to the docs a datetime object is `A combination of a date and a time. Attributes: year, month, day, hour, minute, second, microsecond, and tzinfo.` https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#available-types